# Can a PHP CLI script call itself without forking?

Tags: php, linux

I want a PHP CLI* script to run, do a task, sleep for two seconds, and then run again. Currently, this looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/config/app.php';

$w = new Worker;

if ($w->running) {
    exit;
} elseif ($job = $w->next()) {
    $w->run($job);
    sleep(2);
    exec(__FILE__);
    exit;
} else {
    exit;
}
```

However, it occurs to me that the new run starts before the old run completes. I am mostly a web developer, so am unfamiliar with this level (I’m at home at a somewhat higher level of abstraction), but I think this becomes what’s known as a fork bomb. How can I do this safely?

I’ve read the PHP manual for [`pnctl_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-exec.php), but I’m not confident that I’m understanding it correctly.

---

* It’s done as PHP so most of the actual functionality can be in a library which can also be called from a web interface.

Comment: *Wat?* For one, don't re-execute the entire script, *put a loop in it*. The way you've written this the processes will just accumulate forever, never finishing, until something dies. Probably your server.

Comment: @Sammitch. I suspected as much: that's what I was asking about. (And was expecting a *wat* response, too; as I said, I know I'm out of my depth here.) Admittedly, using a loop *inside* the script is rather obvious in retrospect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply put a loop around your worker and execute it, while it has some jobs to do.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/config/app.php';

$w = new Worker;

if ($w->running) {
    exit;
}

while ($job = $w->next()) {
    $w->run($job);
    sleep(2); // Not sure, if you really need this?
}
```